# My list does not appear when running and no errors pops up

Tags: python, list

My list does not appear when I'm running my program. There are no errors it just pops up with a blank screen.

This is my code. Please help only new to python.

```
devices = ['iphone', 'ps5', 'pc']
devicesaccessories = ['mouse', 'keyboard', 'airpods']
joinedlist = devices + devicesaccessories
```

Comment: What else did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
print(joinedlist)
```

in the end

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
devices = ['iphone', 'ps5', 'pc']
devicesaccessories = ['mouse', 'keyboard', 'airpods']
print(devices + devicesaccessories)
```

or

```
devices = ['iphone', 'ps5', 'pc']
devicesaccessories = ['mouse', 'keyboard', 'airpods']
joinedlist = devices + devicesaccessories
print(joinedlist)
```